# kendo grid view exception "You must use Incell edit mode for batche updates exception"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

i have a kendo grid view with a popup interface when i want to get my view an exception :"You must use Incell edit mode for batche updates"appear
kendo grid:`

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:400px;height:800px; margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;"})
    .Editable(editing =>
        {
            editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("PopupEditors/PopupBareme")
            .Window(w => w.Title("NeoPaie : Ajouter/Modifier une Bareme").Width(400).Height(250));

        })


    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read("Liste", "Bareme")
            .Update("Save", "Bareme")
           .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.BaremeId))
           .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("OnKendoGridAdministrationSaveEnd").Error("OnKendoGridPopupListSaveError"))
            )

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.BaremeId).Groupable(false).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.NOTE).Width(80).Title("Note").Format("{0:n0}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align : left;" }); 
        columns.Bound(p => p.JOURS).Width(100).Title("Nb.Jours").Format("{0:N2}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align :right ;" });
        columns.Command(command => command.Edit().Text(" ")).Width(60).Title("Modifier");
    })
    .Scrollable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
                .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()

  )
```

and ther is my  popup interface should be shown when i want to modify a column value

```
@using System.Collections
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using NeoPaie.ViewModels;
@model  BaremeVM
<div class="popupError"></div>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BaremeId)


<div class="editor-label">NOTE</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NOTE, new { @class = "k-textbox" , @style = "width:140px" })
</div>

<div class="editor-label">JOURS</div>

<div class="editor-field">

@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.JOURS).Step(0.1).Decimals(2).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100px" })
</div>


`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer. Not sur it will work for you but try it.
Normally you have a folder name Shared and maybe Editor Templates. If Editor Templates doesn't exist create it and then put your popup interface in.

In your code when you call your popup try this :

```
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("HelpEdit").Window(w => w.Title("Text").Width(970)))
```

It works fine for me

Hope i can help